# Assimp + OpenGL loads only partly

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, assimp

I am trying to draw a wireframe of ironman model. But some parts are missing and there are extra edges being drawn I feel. Where have I gone wrong?

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
std::vector<GLuint> indices; 
for(unsigned int num_meshes=0; num_meshes<scene->mNumMeshes; num_meshes++)
{
    // lets store all the vertices.
    for(unsigned int num_vertices_per_mesh=0; num_vertices_per_mesh<scene->mMeshes[num_meshes]->mNumVertices; num_vertices_per_mesh++)
    {
        glm::vec3 vertex(scene->mMeshes[num_meshes]->mVertices[num_vertices_per_mesh].x, scene->mMeshes[num_meshes]->mVertices[num_vertices_per_mesh].y, scene->mMeshes[num_meshes]->mVertices[num_vertices_per_mesh].z);
        vertices.push_back(vertex);
    }
    // lets store all the indices or faces.
    for(unsigned int num_faces=0; num_faces<scene->mMeshes[num_meshes]->mNumFaces; num_faces++){
        indices.push_back(scene->mMeshes[num_meshes]->mFaces[num_faces].mIndices[0]);
        indices.push_back(scene->mMeshes[num_meshes]->mFaces[num_faces].mIndices[1]);
        indices.push_back(scene->mMeshes[num_meshes]->mFaces[num_faces].mIndices[2]); 
    }
}

GLfloat *vertices_array = &vertices[0].x;
GLuint size_of_vertices_array = vertices.size() * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat); // vertices data size * x,y,z values per vertex * sizeof(GLfloat)

GLuint *indices_array = indices.data();
GLuint size_of_indices_array = indices.size()*sizeof(GLuint);
// ===========================================================================================
GLuint VBO, VAO, EBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

glBindVertexArray(VAO); // Bind vertex array objects first before VBOs
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size_of_vertices_array, vertices_array, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// attribute 0 vertex positions
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3*sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, size_of_indices_array, indices_array, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(0);               // unbinding VAO

/****** other lines of code ***********/
main_loop()
{
    /***** other lines of code *********/
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

I am getting an image as below. On blender the model loads perfectly.
[image: current output]

Where have I gone wrong? I am able to load objects with only one mesh perfectly!

Comment: Probably the indices of each mesh start at 0. But if you add all the vertices of all the meshes to one and the same container (`std::vector`), then the vertices of the 2nd mesh start after the vertices of the first mesh and so on. You have to add an start offset to to the indices. The start offset is `size_t offset = vertices.size()` at the begin of the outer `for` loop. Note, that's only a guess, because I don't know the indices.

Comment: Yes, I checked. The index of each mesh starts at 0. I totally missed that. Thank you so much.

Comment: You should be using the node-tree (scene->mRoot) for assimp scenes as there may be instanced meshes in there with their own instance relative world-matrices.

Answer (score 1):

As Rabbid76 said before: you need to renumber your indices when all vertices are stored in one vertex buffer. Just increase the current index by the offset of the number of vertices:

```
unsigned int offet = 0;
for(unsigned int num_meshes=0; num_meshes<scene->mNumMeshes; num_meshes++)
{
    // lets store all the vertices.
    for(unsigned int num_vertices_per_mesh=0; num_vertices_per_mesh<scene->mMeshes[num_meshes]->mNumVertices; num_vertices_per_mesh++)
    {
        glm::vec3 vertex(scene->mMeshes[num_meshes]->mVertices[num_vertices_per_mesh].x, scene->mMeshes[num_meshes]->mVertices[num_vertices_per_mesh].y, scene->mMeshes[num_meshes]->mVertices[num_vertices_per_mesh].z);
        vertices.push_back(vertex);
    }
    // lets store all the indices or faces.
    for(unsigned int num_faces=0; num_faces<scene->mMeshes[num_meshes]->mNumFaces; num_faces++){
        indices.push_back(scene->mMeshes[num_meshes]->mFaces[num_faces].mIndices[0]+offet );
        indices.push_back(scene->mMeshes[num_meshes]->mFaces[num_faces].mIndices[1]+offset);
        indices.push_back(scene->mMeshes[num_meshes]->mFaces[num_faces].mIndices[2]+offset); 
    }
    offset += num_vertices_per_mesh;
}
```